# Unable to create socket: Permission denied

Tags: mysql, linux

he estado intentando ingresar al visor de documentos PDF que viene por defecto en deepin (evince) y me aparece este error

```
Unable to init server: Unable to create socket: Permission denied 
Cannot parse arguments: Cannot open display:
```

imagino que pueda deberse a algún daño en los sockets por que también al momento de querer ingresar a mysql me aparece el siguiente error

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

espero que alguien pueda ayudarme.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código que genera estos errores? ¿Aparece información adicional en los logs del servidor o base de datos?

Answer (score 0):

Revisa si tienes instalado `mysql-server`

```
sudo apt list --installed | grep mysql-server
```

Si no, instalalo.

Si ya lo tienes instalado, entonces (re)inicia el servicio con.

```
sudo service mysql start  # o "restart"
```